# How can I clear console but leave needed print-line?

Tags: python

For example I have code:

```py
print("Your status - online")
while(True):
    print("Searching for server")
```

And I need to clear console, but leave "Your status - online", so "Searching for server" isn't overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) to get back to the beginning of the line. Then, when you print, it overrides the previously printed line.

```
print("Your status - online")
while True:
    print("Searching for server", end="\r")
```

Comment: Hm, thank you, that looks intresting for me! :p